# Network share permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, acl, shared-folders

I try to reproduce this:

```
6 users involved: Ann, Betty, Charls, Danny, Edward, Fred
1 share: SHARE
3 folders: Optional, Personal, Questions

SHARE (only those 6 can read)
 |_Optional (only Ann and Betty can write)
 |_Personal (only Charls and Danny can write)
 |_Questions (only Edward and Fred can write)
```

I've tried with SMB permissions, making groups for each pair.
I've made shares for every folder, but not work as I intended.

Can someone tell me what is the best way to reproduce this scenario?
Maybe some tips to point me to the right direction?

Thanks!